# error in stringsAsFactors in R while reading Excel File

Tags: r, excel, string

I wanted to know is there any alternative for `stringsAsFactors` in 'R', I know this works in CSV and XLSX in 'R' studio, but in 'R'  `stringsAsFactors` is not working for reading XLSX file.

```
Sheet3_5K=read.xlsx("Latest Write off Sheet.xlsx",sheet = "£3-5K",stringsAsFactors = F)
```

> ```
> Error in read.xlsx("Latest Write off Sheet.xlsx", sheet = "£3-5K", stringsAsFactors = F) : 
>   unused argument (stringsAsFactors = F)
> ```

My outcome is to refrain 'R' to make factor from chr,and instead want chr to remain as same chr variable

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Which package are you using? `read.xlsx` from the `xlsx` package *does* have the `stringsAsFactors` argument. `read.xlsx` from the `openxlsx` package does not have have a `stringsAsFactors` argument, but it *does not* automatically convert character columns to factor. There is also `read_excel` from the `readxl` package, which also does not convert character columns to factor.

Comment: You can also set the option stringsAsFactors = F at the beginning of your script using options(stringsAsFactors = F) . Then you don't have to worry later.

Comment: Thanks mate! I was using openxlsx and the reason you have mentioned that is correct since Openxlsx doesn't have the same function but xlsx has. Thank once again.

Comment: @Linus Would you mind rephrase in my code how I will write options(stringsAsFactors = F) at beginning, would be much appreciated friend.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `read.xlsx()` function from xlsx package.It reads categorical character variables as factors.

Here is the code for the same:

```
install.packages("xlsx")
library(xlsx)
Data = read.xlsx(filename, 1, header=TRUE, startRow=1)
```