# Unused arguments while using read.xlsx

Tags: r

I am new to R, please help :)
I am trying to read a file using `read.xlsx()` (from the package `xlsx`) in R. I am getting the following error:

```
Error in read.xlsx("survey_all", stringsAsFactors = F) : 
  unused argument (stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Why does it say unused argument?

Comment: The function `read.xlsx()` has no parameter/argument `stringsAsFactors=`

Comment: If you do not want factors, you can use `read_xlsx` function from `readxl` package. It interprets strings as `character` instead of `factor`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `xlsx` library, this should work as you can pass `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` as an additional argument.
However, if you're using `openxlsx`, then this is not an option.

Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514789/error-in-stringsasfactors-in-r-while-reading-excel-file).
Check which library you're using.

Comment: I am using the xlsx library but this still doesn't work. Why is that so?

Comment: I'm really not sure. Try to install the latest version of the `xlsx` and again make sure you're using the correct function.

Comment: You can also try using `read_xlsx` from `readxl` package.